# Invoking another method from proxy invoke method

Tags: java

I have implemented Proxy called `ClientContainerInvocationHandler`. It is used on objects of my class `SocketContainer` which implement interface `IClient` which has method `public int getId()`.

Now I'm trying to invoke a method of the current object under the proxy which is of type `SocketContainer` the `getId()` method I have shown below in the comment (see code below). Is this possible ?

```
public class ClientContainerInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

   private final Object target;

   private ClientContainerInvocationHandler(final Object object) {
     this.target = object;
   }

   public static Object createProxy(final Object object) {
     final Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(object.getClass().getClassLoader(), object.getClass().getInterfaces(), new ClientContainerInvocationHandler(object));
     return proxy;
   }

   @Override
   public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
     if (method.getName().equals("addMessage")) {
       // invoke on the current object
       // the method getID and retrieve the result here
       // I have tried this : 
       //   Method m =target.getClass().getMethod("getId"); 
       // but I get exception if I do this
    }
  }
}
```

Full Exception :

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getID(Unknown Source)
at com.project.chat_system.ChatRoom.addClient(ChatRoom.java:18)
at com.project.chat_system_tests.RealTest.testMessagesReceived(RealTest.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.project.chat_system.SocketContainer.getId()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.project.chat_system_tests.ClientContainerInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientContainerInvocationHandler.java:30)
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: $Proxy7.getID(Unknown Source) ,java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Comment: Please add the exception with all details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this?:

```
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    if (method.getName().equals("addMessage")) {
    // invoke on the current object
    //the method getID and retrieve the result here
    Method getIdMethod = proxy.getClass().getMethod("getID");

    //proxy is the object in which you want to call your method on
    SomeResult result = getIdMethod.invoke(proxy);

    //if you need to pass arguments
    SomeResult result = getIdMethod.invoke(proxy, args);
    }
```

Comment: this invokes the passed method to the object I want some other method.

Comment: @Joel Updated based on your comment.

Comment: This doesn't work I have tried it , cause it makes $Proxy5.getID() and it gives the exception i mentioned